# Porqué no queda visible Control insertado en Windows Forms (VB.NET)

Tags: windows-forms, formularios, visual-studio-2017

Arrastro un control desde Cuadro de Herramientas a un Formulario Windows, utilizando Visual Studio .NET (Basic).

Queda bien registrado en Designer.vb, o sea, la parte Código, pero no se visualiza en la vista de formulario.

Probé con Traer al Frente, Enviar al Fondo. Comprobé la Location y nada. Comparé las Propiedades, con otro control similar de otro Formulario y está todo igual. No sucede siempre, sólo algunas veces e ignoro porqué. No encontré en Internet alguna solución por eso recurro a este Foro.

Si alguien le pasó algo igual y me puede ayudar, desde ya agradecido.

Comment: Tal vez la ubicación en la ventana de fondo o el tamaño del control?

Comment: He dado varios tamaños, varias ubicaciones, todas lógicas, pero nada de nada, no aparece... tuve que crear nuevo formulario... para poder seguir, mientras espero encontrar alguna explicación. Muchas gracias Roger por tu tiempo brindado!

Answer (score 0):

Estimado amigo, a mí me pasó alguna vez y me sigue pasando. No es una solución definitiva porque inopinadamente el problema vuelve a resurgir, pero si vas al Form.Designer, en la parte donde añade el control, simplemente borra un carácter y vuélvelo a escribir. Voilá, se hizo la magia; ¿por qué no lo sé, pero ocurre?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta MMM. El tiempo pasó. Ahora estoy trabajando fuerte en C# y con base de datos Sql Server.